# Why use __dirname along with path.resolve in webpack config?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, path

I was going though this webpack tutorial: https://youtu.be/TOb1c39m64A

At around 1:30:00 mark he discusses the use of `__dirname` in `path.resolve` however I don't quite understand what's the difference between using and not using it.

Dont they both (`path.resolve` & `__dirname`) mean the same thing? Both give the current absolute directory where this file is running. This is confirmed by the fact that when I remove `__dirname` it still creates the `build` files at same root location (even if the `webpack.config.js`) file is not present at the root level. i.e. both the below codes yield same result:

**With `__dirname`**

```
  output: {
    assetModuleFilename: "images/[hash][ext][query]",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
```

**Without `__dirname`:**

```
  output: {
    assetModuleFilename: "images/[hash][ext][query]",
    path: path.resolve('dist')
  },
```

So what is the need to use `__dirname` here??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have right in your scenario they will work in same fashion.

But there is a subtle difference between those two, and I will try to explain it.

**__dirname** in Node script will give you absolute path of the where current JS file resides.

**path.resolve** on the other hand gives you absolute path which if not constructed from path segments, defaults to current working directory. (which is your situation).

There is difference between path of `where js file resides` and `currently working directory`.

How you can find this difference?
In your app you can change current directory using: `processs.chdir(./example)`.

Now if you check your addresses they won't be same. `path.resolve` will also append this `/example` part in yours path. `__dirname` will still reference on the right path.

Shortly in your case they will work exactly same, but `__dirname` is more robust approach.

Comment: The `path` variable in my code is being used by `package.json` file in root directory when I run `npm run build`. There's no other use to it, and i can't run this command from any other `currently working directory` because `package.json` is in root directory only. So is there any usecase why we would want to change directory while running this? Also, apart from my situation, can you give an example where changing directories is required.

Comment: Also, imo using `path.resolve` without `__dirname` seems like more robust approach in my case because we usually want to create `dist` in the root directroy itself. If `webpack.config.js` file is somewhere other than root (eg. `{root}/config/webpack.config.js`), then using `__dirname` approach will create `dist` in `config` folder whereas other approach will stil create it in root which is preferred.

Comment: Here you can find similar explanations as one which I gave you above: webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context. It is different  part of setting, but same goal what we usually want to achieve.
You can also follow steps which I gave you above, create `example` folder and see what will happen in situation. 
As I already said that is not your current situation, but that is one of the reason why we do it on this way.