# readfilesync is not working properly as required

Tags: node.js, json, express

I am trying to store the data of username and password in admins array and then saving that input in a file called admins.json but when i restart my server admin array should have the data present in the file but whenever i am console.log it is showing empty array

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
app.use(express.json());
const fs=require('fs')
let ADMINS = [];
let USERS = [];
let COURSES = [];
console.log(ADMINS);
try{
  ADMINS=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('admins.json','utf8'));
  USERS=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('users.json','utf8'));
  COURSES=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('courses.json','utf8'));
}
catch{
  ADMINS=[];
  USERS=[];
  COURSES=[];
}
console.log(ADMINS);
// Admin routes
var secretkeyadmin='s3cr3tk3yadmin';
var secretkeyuser='s3cr3tkeyuser';
const generatejwt=(admin)=>{
  const token = jwt.sign({
    username:admin.username,
    password:admin.password
  },secretkeyadmin);
  return token;
}
const authenticatejwt=(req,res,next)=>{
  const h=req.headers.authentication;
  const token=h.split(' ')[1];
  if(token){
  const t= jwt.verify(token,secretkeyadmin);
  if(ADMINS.find((a)=>a.username==t.username && a.password==t.password)){
    //res.json("success");
    next();
  }
  else{
    res.json("user does not exist");
  }
}
else{
  res.json("wrong");
}
}
app.post('/admin/signup', (req, res) => {
  // logic to sign up admin
  const admin=req.body;
  
  if(admin){
    if(ADMINS.find((a)=>a.username==admin.username&& a.password==admin.password)){
      res.status(403).json('try another way user exist');
    }
    else {
      ADMINS.push(admin);
      fs.writeFileSync('admins.json',JSON.stringify(ADMINS));
    }
    const token = generatejwt(admin);
    res.json({
      msg:"successful",
      token:token
    })
  }
  
  else res.json("error");
});

app.post('/admin/login', authenticatejwt,(req, res) => {
  // logic to log in admin
  res.json("login successful");
});

app.post('/admin/courses',authenticatejwt, (req, res) => {
  // logic to create a course
   const course=req.body;
   course.id=Date.now();
   COURSES.push(course);
   fs.writeFileSync('courses.json',JSON.stringify(COURSES));
});
```

I am getting output as
[]
[]
infact my second output should be the data stored in admin .json
below is my admins .json file
[{"username":"oojjjo","password":"1234"}]

Comment: You catch and discard an error that could explain what's wrong. Never use ambiguous relative paths, this is possibly the problem here

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69305778/why-use-dirname-along-with-path-resolve-in-webpack-config . Again, you didn't check the error, it should be done on your side and posted